# Domain Name Resolves to different IP on one WIndows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have several domain controllers running, one name resolves to the internal IP, where the name resolves to an external IP on the other domain controllers.  I don't see any entry for the name I am querying, and I don't see the zone.  What might be going on?

**Update:**
I will call the domain I am having trouble with foo.bar.com , and my companies domain baz.com.

Under forward lookup zones, there is no folder for bar.com.  When I run `dig @mydc01 foo.bar.com` I get the internal IP:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
foo.bar.com.    0   IN  A   10.1.1.1
```

When I run the same command against my other DNS servers ( ie @mydc02 ), I get the public IP and the respose with the public name servers being authorative. I have tried clearing cache, and there is no host entry.  I see foo.bar.com as a cached lookup, under the root folder, com folder, bar folder.  In that folder, there is Name: ( Same as parent folder), Type: Name Server, Data: Our public dns servers.

**More Update**:
When I add +trace to dig while still having @problemServer I get the correct IP as the response.

Comment: So when I query the other ones with dig foo.name.com @DC1 , I get the external.  But when I do @DC2 I get the internal IP.

Comment: Are you wanting it to be resolving to the external or internal?  What's the "correct" one?

Comment: TheCleaner: External.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the host file on that server?

Comment: Nope, already Checked that.

Comment: Probably obvious, but there aren't host files on the *other* servers right?

Comment: Nickat, nope.  If even there were, I don't think it would matter with dig if I am selecting the server.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your DC's are MS-DNS servers as well? If so, do they have the same forwarders?

Comment: Exactly, they are DNS servers.  In this case, no forwarders.

Comment: Sorry if silly question; are both DC's getting regular updates for that zone ... check the serial #'s?

Comment: echobeach2, not silly, how do I check that the zone updates?  And what do you mean by the serial numbers?

Comment: By "zone updates", I assuming you have a zone transfer of that zone that perhaps is out of date.

However, even if you don't have a ZT of it ...

DNS admin tool, or "nslookup -type=soa foo.bar.com" on command line which should output "serial =". Interestingly, this exact command works ... someone must have that domain!

Answer (score 0):

I would verify that your "problem" server is pointing to the same DNS server as the other DC's.  If it is pointing to itself then make sure that the DNS cache is flushed (as John said)...ipconfig /flushdns, then try the resolution again.

Also, try using dig with the full output and see if you can determine where in DNS the invalid record is located.

Make sure you are really resolving this via DNS as well.  Are you querying by FQDN or just NETBIOS name?  Sometimes WINS (if around) can cause discrepancies for short name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of your registered DNS servers against the order in the other servers that work.